# Using Angular Factory not retrieving bit.ly URL

Tags: angularjs, factory

I'm trying to create a factory in Angular which takes an encoded URL and returns a shortened bit.ly link. The code works within a controller, but when I try and put that same code in a factory I can't get it to return the link. Here is my factory:

```
myAppModule.factory('BitlyBuilder', function($http){
return {
    buildBitlyUrl: function(link1){
        $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=mytokenhere&longUrl='+link1}).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                return data.data.url;})
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('bit.ly failed us');
            });
    }
}});
```

Now here is the code in the controller I'm using to call the factory service:

```
var encodedLink = encodeURIComponent($scope.feed1.feedlink);
        $scope.shortURL = function (encodedLink) {
            return BitlyBuilder.buildBitlyUrl(encodedLink);
        }
        console.log($scope.shortURL);
```

What I get when I console.log it is:

```
function (encodedLink) {
            return BitlyBuilder.buildBitlyUrl(encodedLink);
        }
```

I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't quite get it. Thanks for help in advance...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the shortURL function is not getting called. Try using this for your console.log call:

```
console.log( $scope.shortURL(encodedLink) )
```

Comment: That errors with: Property 'shortURL' of object #<h> is not a function". Which I thought it would. shortURL is not a function. I know I have a valid "encodedLink", but it is not calling the function. I suspect I need some kind of callback, but not sure how to implement that.

Comment: Hmm, I think shortURL is a function. Here's a [link to a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ne5P8/333/) that calls the factory method using shortURL.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you aren't returning anything from `BitlyBuilder.buildBitlyUrl`. Returning something from within `success` and `error` handlers does no good, you are returning within a closed function.

Even if you were returning anything, your `console.log($scope.shortURL);` doesn't take into account that `$http` is asynchronous

Try this:

```
myAppModule.factory('BitlyBuilder', function($http){
return {
    buildBitlyUrl: function(link1){
      /* return request itself*/
       return $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=mytokenhere&longUrl='+link1})
            /* will get data in controller */
           /* .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                return data.data.url;})*/
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('bit.ly failed us');
            });
    }
}});
```

In controller:

```
 BitlyBuilder.buildBitlyUrl(encodedLink).success(function(data){
        $scope.shortURL=data.url;// assumes response is {url:'urlstring'}*/
         console.log( $scope.shortURL);
 })
```